# Why does viewbox attribute affect the size of the SVG element?

Tags: html, css, svg

An empty SVG (`<svg></svg>`) will render as 300px × 150px. I can easily set the dimensions (say, `<svg width="100" height="100"></svg>`). But why does including a viewbox change the default width to 100%, and the height to 75% of the width? I tested a minimal element: `<svg viewbox="100 100 200 150"></svg>` Try this example:

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
<style>
body {background-color: lightblue;}
svg {background-color: yellow;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<svg></svg>
<p>
<svg width="100" height="100"></svg>
<p>
<svg viewbox="100 100 200 150"></svg>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

This is because an <SVG> element in HTML is an *Inline, replaced element*.

[The rules for setting the size of Inline, replaced elements](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visudet.html#inline-replaced-width) are

> - If 'height' and 'width' both have computed values of 'auto' and the
>     element also has an intrinsic width, then that intrinsic width is the
>     used value of 'width'.
> - If 'height' and 'width' both have computed values of 'auto' and the
>     element has no intrinsic width, but does have an intrinsic height and
>     intrinsic ratio; or if 'width' has a computed value of 'auto',
>     'height' has some other computed value, and the element does have an
>     intrinsic ratio; then the used value of 'width' is:
>
>   ```
>   (used height) * (intrinsic ratio)
>   ```
> - If 'height' and 'width' both have computed values of 'auto' and the
>     element has an intrinsic ratio but no intrinsic height or width, then
>     the used value of 'width' is undefined in CSS 2.2. However, it is
>     suggested that, if the containing block's width does not itself depend
>     on the replaced element's width, then the used value of 'width' is
>     calculated from the constraint equation used for block-level,
>     non-replaced elements in normal flow.
> - Otherwise, if 'width' has a computed value of 'auto', and the element
>     has an intrinsic width, then that intrinsic width is the used value of
>     'width'.
> - Otherwise, if 'width' has a computed value of 'auto', but none of the
>     conditions above are met, then the used value of 'width' becomes
>     300px. If 300px is too wide to fit the device, UAs should use the
>     width of the largest rectangle that has a 2:1 ratio and fits the
>     device instead.

In the first case, we fall right in the last option

```
(width: auto, height: auto) => height = 300, width = height * 1 / 2 = 150
```

In the second case, they do have non-auto values set, so these values are used.

In the third case, setting the viewBox attribute does define an *intrinsic ratio*, but no *intrinsic size*, so we fall in the third case, which is kind of an undefined behavior, even though it is suggested that "*the used value of 'width' is calculated from the constraint equation used for block-level, non-replaced elements in normal flow.*".
This means `width = 100%, height = width * ratio = width * 150 / 200`).

```js
const width = cont.offsetWidth;
const ratio = (150 / 200); // viewBox's height / viewBox's width
const height = width * ratio;

console.log('calculated height', height);
console.log('measured height', elem.getBoundingClientRect().height);
```

```css
#elem {background: yellow;}
```

```html
<p id="cont">
  <svg id="elem" viewBox="100 100 200 150"></svg>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Viewbox defines how all the lengths and coordinates used inside the SVG should be scaled to fit the total space available.

Your canvas is set as the total viewport of your browser window.

You have given `viewbox="100 100 200 150"` which means the cordinates x,y are 100 and 100.

200 and 150 gives the ratio of how the canvas is filled.

Since 150 is 75% of 200, the canvas gets filled 100% to the width and 75% of height available.

The results are same for `viewbox="100 100 20 15"` or any other similar ratio that calculates 1:3/4